# jQuery: Get random item from array and assign class once

Tags: jquery, arrays, random, element

I'm relatively new in jQuery, or any script for that matter. I tried several approaches, but can't seem to get the effect i want.

What i want is:

- Get the list of elements, divs in this case
- Assign a unique class or ID to 5 of them

I have managed to assign the unique class, but this involves running a new function 5 times. And sometimes the same div gets multiple classes.

My code so far:

```js
var places2beObj = $('#blokken_clubinfo > div');

$.makeArray(places2beObj);


console.log(places2beObj);

function randomPlace2be1() {
  var randomPlace = places2beObj[Math.floor(Math.random() * places2beObj.length)];
  $(randomPlace).addClass("random1", function() {
    places2beObj.splice(randomPlace, 1);
  });
}

function randomPlace2be2() {
  var randomPlace = places2beObj[Math.floor(Math.random() * places2beObj.length)];
  $(randomPlace).addClass("random2", function() {
    places2beObj.splice(randomPlace, 1);
  });
}

randomPlace2be1()
randomPlace2be2()
```

Comment: You have two functions, should each of the randomly-chosen elements get both classes? Or should there be two sets of elements, one getting the `'kaolo'` class and the otehr set getting `'goon'` class?

Comment: These functions are just test / fake classes.

If it can be done in 1 function, that would be better. But i simply don't know how to do that.

Comment: Do *what* precisely? Add a class to *n* random elements? Multiple classes?

Comment: There will be lot's of divs with the same style. To promote some of them, i want to style 5 of them differently. 
Therefore, i want to randomly assign classes to 5 of these divs.

Like large1, large2, small1, small2, wide

Comment: So, out of the set of `<div>` elements, you want to randomly select five of those `<div>`s, and assign a classes to them? I'd suggest that adding a simple class, like `large` or `small` would be more sensible (since that way you can only write one class in your CSS), but if you're willing to write out a potentially large nummber of classes `large1, large2, large3...large30043` then fair enough, I guess. So: two randomly-selected sets of five? Each group being given a class of `large` or `small`, with a numeric suffix? And no element should have both?

Comment: Yes, precisely. There won't be a large number of classes, just those 5. And indeed, no element should have both.

So you'd get a list of divs, with only 5 divs with the extra class

Comment: What a frustrating site this is... only allowed to edit a comment for a limited time :(
I wanted to add this:
So you'd get a list of divs, with only 5 divs with the extra class. But not 2 groups, just 5 classes randomly added to 1 element

Comment: @user1376510 The errors you've got can only happen when `places2beObj` contains less than five divs. I added a little security check for that.

Comment: @user1376510 I can't load the url you've posted. I've added a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ww9djtaL/2/) to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var places2beObj = $('#blokken_clubinfo > div').get(), // returns an array with all selected divs
    length = places2beObj.length,
    classes = ['large1', 'large2', 'small1', 'small2', 'wide'], // define the classes to apply
    randoms = [];

for (var num, l = length, i = 0; i < 5 && i < l; i++) {
    do { num = Math.floor(Math.random() * length) } // get a random num
    // when element is already choosen get another num
    while ($.inArray(places2beObj[num], randoms) != -1);
    randoms.push(places2beObj.splice(num, 1)); // snip out element and push it into randoms array
    $(randoms[i]).addClass(classes[i]); length--; // add class and decrement length
};
```

Now randoms-array holds five randomly choosen elements with a new class added, and these elements are removed from places2beObj-array. If you don't want to remove them from there but only randomly add classes the `for-loop` looks like this:

```
for (var num, i = 0; i < 5 && i < length; i++) {
    do { num = Math.floor(Math.random() * length) } // get a random number
    // when number is already choosen get another number
    while ($.inArray(num, randoms) != -1);
    $(places2beObj[num]).addClass(classes[i]);
    randoms.push(num); // push num into randoms to remember what has been choosen already
};
```

Now five elements have got a random class and randoms holds the indices of these elements in places2beObj.

**EDIT**: according to your comment: It's only a very basic javascript `for-loop`. At first a variable called i is defined being 0; in the middle is a condition `i < 5` (= i must be smaller than 5). As long as the condition is true the code inside `{}` is executed again and again. After each execution i gets incremented by 1 (`i++` == `i += 1`). Now i makes 5 steps: 0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5: After the fifth step the condition is false, because 5 is not smaller than 5, and the loop stops.

`$.inArray(element, array)` is a jQuery-function that looks whether an element (can be anything: DOM-element, Number, String, ...) is member of an array. If it's found the function returns the index (= a number telling at which place in array it sits). If it's not found the function returns -1. We use it here to check if an element (or a random number) has been choosen yet to avoid one element getting two ore more classes.

**EDIT 2**: To avoid crashes if `places2beObj` has less than five elements I've added a little security. The working [FIDDLE here](http://jsfiddle.net/ww9djtaL/2/) shows nine divs, each time you **run** that fiddle five of them gets randomly colored. Make shure you use only one of the both for-loops shown here.

Comment: I really don't understand all this i = 0 and i++ stuff, but it works exactly like i want to! :) Thanks a lot! 

How did you learn this? I mean, i can change elements, animate them etc. but i wouldn't know where to start on this one.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't entirely work :( It will just distribute those classes over the first 5 div's. It doesn't add the classes to a random div in the list.

Comment: @user1376510 Thanks for feedback. I made a mistake: `Math.random` is a function returning a random number between 0 and 1. It must be called with `Math.random()`, **parentheses added!** Multiplied with `places2beObj.length` it picks the elements randomly, but only when there are more than five.

Comment: @user1376510 Are you sure you have '$(places2beObj[**num**])' in the for-loop, **not** '$(places2beObj[**i**])' ?

Comment: Now it crashes Firefox :D It prompts the "unresponsive script" box. And it seems to distribute the classes over all the div's, not just 1 for each class :(

Comment: I copied the full code again, to make sure all is correct. I currently have 9 divs in the $('#blokken_clubinfo > div')

Here's the applied script:
http://dance2experience.nl/wordpress/place2be/

Comment: Yup, works like a charm now! Forgot to remove one of the for loops. Thanks for your time, effort and explanation of your script!

Answer (score 0):

If the divs have a common class then the following function will be useful

```
$('.common').each(function (i) {
    $(this).addClass('common-' + i);
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't really get it. What does + i do here?

Comment: `i` is the index of the current element jQuery is iterating over from amongst the collection returned by the selector; this will add a class of `common-0` to the first, `common-1` to the second, etc.

Comment: Ah i see. But i want to add 5 unique classes while there will be far more elements.